# Stanford CoreNLP version change in pom.xml causing error

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford CoreNLP on Ubuntu 14.04 and facing the following issue when I run the following code:

**Java Code:**

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

/*import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.TaggedWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.shiftreduce.ShiftReduceParser;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;*/

import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;

public class App
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, NoClassDefFoundError
    {
        MaxentTagger tagger = null;
        if(tagger == null)
        {
            tagger = new MaxentTagger("mymodel.tagger");
        }
        System.out.println("Let's do this!");
    }
}
```

**Command Run:**

> mvn clean install exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.mycompany.app.App

**Terminal Output:**

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.2:jar (default-jar) @ dt_mvn ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/sidharth/Desktop/dt_mvn/target/dt_mvn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3:install (default-install) @ dt_mvn ---
[INFO] Installing /home/sidharth/Desktop/dt_mvn/target/dt_mvn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/sidharth/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/app/dt_mvn/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dt_mvn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/sidharth/Desktop/dt_mvn/pom.xml to /home/sidharth/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/app/dt_mvn/1.0-SNAPSHOT/dt_mvn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 

[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ dt_mvn ---
Reading POS tagger model from mymodel.tagger ... [WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00048E4D
    at edu.stanford.nlp.maxent.iis.LambdaSolve.read_lambdas(LambdaSolve.java:726)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.LambdaSolveTagger.<init>(LambdaSolveTagger.java:76)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:863)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:767)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:298)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:263)
    at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:22)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00048E4D
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.maxent.iis.LambdaSolve.read_lambdas(LambdaSolve.java:719)
    ... 12 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.260s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Dec 20 01:34:29 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/228M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project dt_mvn: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00048E4D -> [Help 1]
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>dt_mvn</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>dt_mvn</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
      <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

However, changing version in pom.xml from 3.5.2 to 1.3.0 works correctly. What could be the reason for this?

Thanks!

**P.S.** 
If it's of any use, the maven project was created by the following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=dt_mvn -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect however you built "mymodel.tagger" is incompatible with later versions so the deserialization is failing.  What version did you use to build my_model.tagger?  Does your Maven project fail if you use 1.3.5 ?  I can see changes in our repo in LambdaSolve.java involving serialization in the time period between 1.3.1 and 1.3.5 so I suspect that is the reason.

Also make sure you use Java 1.8 with Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.0 or later.

Comment: Yes, it did fail with 1.3.5 too. I was training the tagger using stanford-postagger-2011-04-20.jar which is an older version but when I changed to stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar, the issue was resolved.